# MySQL UPDATE INNER JOIN with AES_DECRYPT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, encryption

```
UPDATE table_one a 
INNER JOIN table2 b on AES_DECRYPT(a.username, '$key') = AES_DECRYPT(b.username, '$key')
SET a.unit = b.unit, a.unitb = b.unitb;
```

Problem: Need to update `table_one` with the new units from `table_two`.

Question 1: I've ran this SQL and it seems to not be updating the `unit` field in `table_one`. Is my syntax incorrect for that?

Question 2: Is there a better way to compare the username's since they are encrypted (Yes, they have to stay encrypted in the database)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The syntax looks correct to me. If you do a `SELECT` with the same join, do you get any results?

Comment: If the usernames are all encrypted with the same key, you can just compare the usernames directly, you don't need to decrypt them.

Comment: Ill try the select when get a moment.

From my experiences with hash tables, the encrypted output can have the same results. Would that apply to AES?

Comment: Encryption isn't hashing. Encryption has to be 1-to-1. Otherwise, how could you decrypt it and be sure you'll get the original text?

Comment: Select matching emails yield 6 results.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I've just compared usernames directly.